# Puppeteer with DigitalOcean App throws error

Tags: express, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I've created a DigitalOcean App that takes a screenshot and I'm using DigitalOcean spaces to save the image response.

Saving the image response is good. I've used some other image to try.

But the Puppeteer seems to be causing an issue. It throws the following error. It works fantastic on local though.

Here is the error that I see on Deployment Logs

````
[myapp] [2023-07-09 10:33:46] /workspace/node_modules/chromium/lib/chromium/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared```
````